# Is square of an absolutely continuous random variable also absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable (on some probability space) such that the distribution of $X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Can we conclude that $X^2$, which is also a random variable, is absolutely continuous?

I am really a newbie in probability theory, and I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: More generally, if $X$ is absolutely continuous, and $\phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, does it follow that $\phi(X)$ is absolutely continuous?  What about $\phi$ Borel measurable?

Comment: The usual change of variables formula requires $\phi$ to be injective and $C^1$ on finitely many open sets $U_i$ such that $\cup_i U_i$ has full probability under $X$.

Comment: @GEdgar: You need more than that; what if $\phi$ is constant?

Comment: @GEdgar To my surprise, this is true for $X^2$, $\sin X$ and $\lfloor X\rfloor$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$ (so that the density of the distribution of $X$ is equal to $F'$ almost everywhere). Then, $\mathbb{P}(X^2\leq x)=1_{x\geq 0}\mathbb{P}(X\in [-\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x}])=1_{x\geq 0}(F(\sqrt{x})-F(-\sqrt{x}))$, which is almost everywhere differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ with derivative $g(x):=1_{x\geq 0} \frac{F'(\sqrt{x})+F'(-\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}},$ which is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)\textrm{d}x=1$. It follows that the distribution $X^2$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lesbegue measure with density $g$.

More abstractly, you can apply the Radon-Nikodym Theorem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more? Since it well known that a.e. differentiability of cumulative distribution function does not imply absolute continuity, why is the phrase "it follows that ~~~" true?

Comment: Well, if your measure has distribution function $F$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} F'\textrm{d}x=1,$ then it certainly follows. The problem with a.e. differentiability is that you might miss some $\delta$ measures in your distribution.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to see that this is true is to apply the Jordan-Hahn decomposition of the measure corresponding to $F$ with respect to the Lesbegue measure.

Comment: So the key point is that: we could integrate $g$ to recover the distribution function of $X^2$?

Comment: Just so. That is what the above calculation shows.

Comment: Okay, I see the point. However, there are singular continuous measures (e.g. Cantor distribution). How can we assure that such cases won't appear?

Comment: You need to add that $g$ is integrable, otherwise the reasoning might fail.

Comment: The Cantor function has derivative $0$. Therefore, its derivative cannot be the density of a probability distribution.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Integrable with integral $1$ is a good point that I'm gonna emphasise.

Comment: Okay, so a final comment: we integrate $g$ on $[a,b]$ ($0<a<b$) with change of variables $\sqrt x = u$ (since $\sqrt x$ is $C^1$, this is justified), and let $a \rightarrow 0$ by using the monotone convergence theorem. Am I right in filling the details?

Comment: Yes. That's the way to go about the other direction.

Comment: And I guess, there is a detail that right continuous functions that agree almost everywhere are, in fact, equal everywhere.

Comment: Oh, one last point of interest: It is, to my knowledge, always true that if $\mu$ has distribution function $F,$ then $\mu$ is ALWAYS equal to the weak derivative of $F$ (where we identify a function $f$ with the measure $f(x)dx$).